# ERROR ReferenceError: "Buffer is not defined" while `ng build`

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use Buffer in my angular component ts for encoding Authorization string.

It is not compiling with `ng build`. I tried `npm i @types/node` and added "node" to types field in tsconfig.json. But error is still there.

***Following is error detail:***

```
ERROR in src/app/register/register.component.ts(40,29): error TS2591: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
```

***Here is code of register.component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User, PricingPlan } from 'api';
import * as EmailValidator from 'email-validator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  model = new User();
  passwordRepeat = '';
  pricingPlans: PricingPlan[];
  userExist = false;

  serverUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/';
  registerSuccess = false;
  registerFailed = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .get(`${this.serverUrl}pricingplans`)
      .subscribe((pricingplans: PricingPlan[]) => {
        this.pricingPlans = pricingplans;
      });
  }

  validateEmail(em) {
    return EmailValidator.validate(em);
  }

  validatePasswords() {
    return this.passwordRepeat === this.model.password;
  }

  save() {
    const auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(this.model.email).toString('base64');

    this.http.get(`${this.serverUrl}user`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: auth
      }
    }).subscribe((responce: User) => {
      this.userExist = (responce.email === this.model.email);
    });

    if (this.userExist) {
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

***Following is my tsconfig.json***

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Comment: `Buffer` is not available in frontend JS anyways, so you might want to look at another way to do what you want. Also `Buffer.from` expects an `integer[]`, and not a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Buffer by this command in your machine

```
npm install Buffer
```

Then you may import Buffer in your register.component.ts as

```
import * as Buffer from "Buffer";
```

Now you can use Buffer, hopefully there would be no problem