# How to display image fetched from S3

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to fetch Image from S3 and display in browser using node.js implementation.

Here is my code:

S3 Client:

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

export class S3Client {
    async getImage(bucket: string, key: string) {
        AWS.config.update({
            accessKeyId: "",
            secretAccessKey: ""
        });

        let s3 = new AWS.S3();

        const data = s3.getObject(
            { Bucket: bucket, Key: key }
        ).promise();

        if (data) {
            Logger.log(
                'Found data for key : ' + data,
                S3Client.name
            );

            return data;
        } else {
            Logger.log(
                'No data found for key : ' + key,
                S3Client.name
            );

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

S3Controller:

```
import {
    Controller,
    Param,
    Get,
    Logger,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import {
    ApiOperation,
    ApiParam,
    ApiResponse,
    ApiTags,
} from '@nestjs/swagger';

import { S3Client } from 'nvc-ms-core';

@ApiTags('S3')
@Controller('s3')

export class S3Controller {
    constructor(
        private readonly s3Client: S3Client,
    ) { }

    @Get('find/:bucket/:key')
    @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Get Image by Bucket Name and Key' })
    @ApiParam({
        name: 'bucket',
        description: 'Bucket Name to search by',
        schema: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        required: true,
    })
    @ApiParam({
        name: 'key',
        description: 'Key to search by',
        schema: {
            type: 'string',
        },
        required: true,
    })
    @ApiResponse({
        status: 200,
        description: 'Retrieved Image by Bucket Name and Key Successfully',
    })
    async findImageByBucketNameAndKey(
        @Param()
        params: {
            bucket: string;
            key: string;
        },
    ): Promise<any | null> {
        const bucketName = params.bucket;
        const key = params.key;
        Logger.log(
            'findImageByBucketNameAndKey(@Param() ' + bucketName + ', ' + key + ' )',
            S3Controller.name,
        );
        return this.s3Client.getImage(bucketName, key);
    }
}
```

Client Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RequestClientService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    findImageByBucketNameAndKey(bucketName: string, key: string): Observable<any | null> {
        return this.http.get<any | null>(environment.baseUrl + `s3/find/${bucketName}/${key}`);
    }
}
```

Component:

```
import {
    Component,
    Input,
    OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';
import { RequestClientService } from 'projects/ui-shared-lib/src/public-api';

@Component({
    selector: 'mvc-request',
    templateUrl: './request.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./request.component.css'],
})
export class RequestComponent implements OnInit {
    requestId: string = '';
    image: any = {};
    
    constructor(
        private readonly requestClientService: RequestClientService,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getImage();
    }


    getImage(): void {
        const key = '12345.jpg';
        this.requestClientService.findImageByBucketNameAndKey('my-image-bucket', key)
            .subscribe((image) => {
                if (image) {
                    //let fileReader = new FileReader();
                    //let imageData = fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(image);
                    console.log('imageData: ' + JSON.stringify(image));
                    //this.vbrImage = "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," + this.encode(image) + "'" + "/>";
                }

            });
    }
}
```

I am not able to use the encode function (commented out) to prepend the mime type and encode the data. I get 'ERROR ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined'. I tried to install buffer as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59173234/error-referenceerror-buffer-is-not-defined-while-ng-build). Installing the buffer didn't solve the issue. I tried if I can convert the response to ByteArray. That is available for Blob and I cannot cast my response to Blob. I wanted to see if I am getting the data in the component and I added JSON.stringify and I see the response data in console. Encode function is taken from [here](https://aws.plainenglish.io/using-node-js-to-display-images-in-a-private-aws-s3-bucket-4c043ed5c5d0). How can I convert the response data to an image and display in browser. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: A simple solution to display S3-hosted images is to supply pre-signed URLs to the front-end. There's no need to proxy the file downloads yourself. Also, there's a lot of code here that seems to be unrelated to your problem. This makes it difficult for people to help you. You should always try to post a minimal example that exhibits the error.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I added all the components I have in place. The real problem is with the Component where I have the getImage() function which gets the data from S3 and transforms to image to be displayed.